# Get Text in specific location of PDF FILE

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I am working on how to merge `pdf_file1` to `pdf_file2`. I need to merge `pdf_file1` to specific pages in file 2. to be able to do that I need to find specific keyword in header of `pdf_file2`

EX: If (keyword == header_of_pdf_file2) then
    **Merge file**

here is my current code to merge the 2 pdf

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi.php');

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pdf->setSourceFile("pdf_file1");
$tplIdxA = $pdf->importPage(1, '/MediaBox');

$pagecnt=$pdf->setSourceFile("pdf_file2.pdf");
$x=1;
  for($i=0; $i<$pagecnt; $i++){
$tplIdxB = $pdf->importPage(intval($i+1), '/MediaBox');
$pdf->addPage();
// place the imported page of the first document:
if($i==0){
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxA, 0, 0, 210,300);
// place the imported page of the snd document:
}
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdxB, 0, 0, 200,295);
    $x=($i+1)*20;
 }

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: And what is your question?